# DialogFlow agent jump to Google Assistant result

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Today I got a problem. That, I'm building an agent to control my home through ESP8266. I control light and fan. Last 2 or 3 days, it's work OK but today when I speak a command relate to "light" keyword, it jump to google search result, google assistant answer me or some time ask me to connect google home devices. My agent didn't process my command and then agent be exited. 
Is there any update of google assistant last 2 days.

Any one have experience about similar issue please help me.
Debug in simulator have nothing to be seen.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you following the [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Your test session has expired. Relaunch your app via the simulator.